# Homework: Java BST without nodes (BST of BSTs)

Tags: java

Note: BST - Binary Search Tree (initialism)

As the title says,
this is a homework assignment so I'm not looking for the answer.
Instead, I just need a point in the right direction.

For the assignment,
I am supposed to create a BST class that is directly defined as some data that holds at most 2 BST children
(i.e. does not use a helper node class).

I am given a class that is annotated with JavaDocs and am supposed to fill in the TODOS.

What is tripping me up at least getting started is implementing the insert method about halfway through the class.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A class to implement the Binary Search Tree data structure.
 * The structure is generic in the type of Objects it contains.
 * @param <T> the type of the contained elements this structure is to hold
 */
public class BinarySearchTree<T> {
private Comparator<T> comparator;
private T data;
private BinarySearchTree<T> left;
private BinarySearchTree<T> right;

/**
 * Constructs an empty BST with a Comparator
 * @param comp the Comparator to use to impose an ordering on instances of T
 */
public BinarySearchTree(Comparator<T> comp) {
    this.comparator = comp;
}

/**
 * Constructs a BST with data and a Comparator
 * @param data the data this BST should hold
 * @param comp the Comparator to use to impose an ordering on instances of T
 */
public BinarySearchTree(T data, Comparator<T> comp) {
    this.data = data;
    this.comparator = comp;
}

/**
 * Inserts an element into this BST
 * @param element the element to insert into this BST
 */
public void insert(T element) {
    //TODO
    if(left == null && right == null){
        left = new BinarySearchTree(element, comparator);
    }else{
        /**
         *Do something with the comparator to figure out if the element goes         
         *to left or right?
         */
    }
}

/**
 * Searchs for a given element in this BST
 * @param element the element to search this BST for
 * @return the element in this BST matching the given element, if found,
 *         otherwise null if the given element is not in this BST
 */
public T find(T element) {
    // TODO
}

/**
 * Gathers all the elements of this BST in order
 * @return a List holding the elements in this BST in order
 */
public List<T> getElements() {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // TODO
    return list;
}

/**
 * Pretty prints the contents of this BST in a horizontal tree-like fashion
 */
public void prettyPrint() {
    prettyPrint(0);
}

private void prettyPrint(int indentLevel) {
    // TODO
    // similar to printInOrder from assignment09,
    // but print `indentLevel` amount of spaces before printing data on its own line
    // you may use a for loop to print `indentLevel` amount of spaces
    // each time you recurse, you add to indentLevel
}

/**
 * A main method supplied for any debugging needs
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Up to you how you use this main method, feel free to change it
    Comparator<Integer> intComp = (i, j) -> i - j; // lambda expression
    BinarySearchTree<Integer> tree = new BinarySearchTree<>(intComp);
    tree.insert(3);
    tree.insert(8);
    tree.insert(1);
    tree.insert(0);
    tree.insert(3);
    tree.insert(9);
    tree.insert(4);
    tree.prettyPrint();
}
```

}

I feel like I understand the concept of how it works, but I have no idea how to implement the code.

I apologize for the formatting if it is unreadable or if this is way too much information to share for the a little assistance.

Comment: Is there nothing more specified about the binary tree in your assignment? The reason I'm asking is that technically if you always add every new element to the left (effectively ending up with a singly linked list), that's still a valid binary tree. What makes a binary tree efficient is not its binary-ness but the way it is balanced, and there are many ways to achieve that. (e.g. red-black trees, AVL trees, splay trees and so on)

Comment: Wouldn't adding everything to one side not work since some elements could potentially be greater than a "node" thus making them belong on the right?
Edit: Just adding everything to one side would be just as effective as having a list of the elements, I would think.

Comment: Well, you'd have to traverse the tree to find the place you can legally insert the new element, but my point really is that trying to write a "generic binary tree" doesn't make much sense in practice. Surely they must have said something about what type of binary tree they expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BST class is the node.
First, decide if a null element is less than or greater than a non-null element.
To implement the insert you need to do the following:

1) Verify that the element parameter is not null.  If it is null, do nothing.

2) The uncompleted code must decide where to insert the element.

a) If one of the children is null you will end up with neither children being null after the insert.  Compare the new element to the non-null element; the greater of the two is the right child.

b) if neither child is null, determine where to put the new element (less than left, use left.  greater than left, use right) and call the insert for that element.

Note: in case you have not already noticed, this assignment is about recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about recursion. I think that was where I was failing to even begin understanding the assignment.